# How to add custom domain to rest api which was created by aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Does amplify provide option to create rest api with custom domain name?
I have searched the amplify document but did not see that mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you can do this via amplify CLI itself but you can always go to the generated API Gateway and follow these steps to add domain.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html